# Search Bar based on json http request with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, uisearchbar

I have a search bar and I wanted to search a json http url by serial number. So if I execute the following json url:

```
http://www.ddproam.co.za/Central/Asset/AssetsWithSerial?Serial=S00000001
```

Actual output:

```
[{"AssetID":1,"AssetName":"Asset 1","AssetDesc":"This is a manually inserted Asset","AssetTypeID":1,"AssetTypeDesc":"This is a manually inserted Asset Type"}]
```

I am trying to search through a search bar say serial S00000001 to populate my Table Cell with the AssetName of the json call.

I have put my json into an array and am trying to execute but I get a app crash error stating:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *loadedSearches;


'-[__NSArrayI objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d857700'
```

Here is my code:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

NSString *searchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ddproam.co.za/Central/Asset/AssetsWithSerial?Serial='%@'",searchText];

searchQuery = [searchQuery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:searchQuery];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
                                     {
                                         self.loadedSearches = JSON[@"AssetName"];

                                         // refreshing the TableView when the block gets the response
                                         [searchTableView reloadData];
                                     }
                                                                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                                     }];

[operation start];


}

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//return self.loadedSearches.count;
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.loadedSearches.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

 if (self.loadedSearches[indexPath.row] == 0) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TableCell Tapped" message:@"Yeah you tapped a table cell" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
NSLog(@"indexPath.row=%d loadedSearches.count=%d", indexPath.row, self.loadedSearches.count);

cell.textLabel.text = self.loadedSearches[indexPath.row][@"AssetName"];
return cell;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  // Perform segue to candy detail
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TableCell Tapped" message:@"Yeah you tapped a table cell" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

I think I am getting an error here:

```
      self.loadedSearches = JSON[@"AssetName"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to access an `NSArray` by key: `JSON[@"AssetName"]`. That would work for an `NSDictionary` but won't for an `NSArray`. So here you need to know what kind of class is your `JSON` variable. If it does match the sample data you posted, it must be an array, containing a dictionary: `[{}]`. You may want to convert it into an simple array so that you can display it in your table view:

```
NSDictionary *d = [JSON lastObject]; // the dictionary contained in the JSON array
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array]; // the array the table view will display

// enumerate on all key/value pair of the dictionary
[d enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    // create a string with key and value separated by a colon
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", key, obj];
    // add this string to the array
    [a addObject:s];
}];

// store the array, which now contains all the key/value pairs as strings, in loadedSearched
self.loadedSearches = a;
```